# Compare items in list with each other

Tags: python, list, datetime, compare

I did try to figure this out, but I am always getting index out of bounds or skipping some cases.
I have list of times:

```
list = ["8:00:33","8:05:02","8:06:12","8:58:17","8:58:58","9:53:11","11:03:54","11:45:51","13:54:42"]
```

I want to split this list into smaller chunks (lists) with 15 minutes diffrence from first.
Expected output:

```
list=[["8:00:33","8:05:02","8:06:12"],["8:58:17","8:58:58"],["9:53:11","11:03:54"],["11:45:51"]...)
```

I hope you get what I want, ask any question and sorry for bad english.
Thank you for your time and help :)

I got this far:

```py
start=list[0]
firstchunk.append(list[0])
for i in range(len(list)-1):
    if(int(time_diff(start,list[i+1])<900)): // time_diff is function that checks if times are 15 min apart
        firstchunk.append(list[i+1])
        print("Start: ",start," End: ",list[i+1])
    else:
        start=list[i+1]
        print("Finished chunk")
        result.append(firstchunk)
        firstchunk=[start]
    if(int(time_diff(start,list[i+1])>5400)): //ignore this part
        print("Start: ",start)
```

Can you help with better solutions
Edit:
Thanks for the comments and solutions. Special thanks to Alain T.
Fastest of cars and most of money for you my brother. Thank you once again to all good people of stack overflow. I wish you a good and long life <3

Comment: You need a result list to which you can append the finished chunks.

Comment: I did edit script, but still no luck. It doesn't work after first result.

Comment: 15 minutes difference between adjacent elements or 15 min in the total time windows? For example, how should be splitted ["8:00:00", "8:10:00", "8:20:00"]?

Comment: Don't clear `firstchunk` but set `firstchunk = []`.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly It should be like this:  ["8:00:00", "8:10:00"],["8:20:00"] because you start from 8:00:00 and check 15 mins apart, it's more than that you start over with next one(in this example is 8:20:00)

Comment: Sorry, I oversaw `start`, therefore `firstchunk = [start]` instead.

Comment: Still no luck from this: ['08:00:33', '08:05:02', '08:58:17', '08:58:58', '09:53:11', '11:03:54', '11:04:53', '11:45:51', '11:50:26', '12:55:20', '13:54:20'] I got this: [['08:00:33', '08:05:02'], ['08:58:17', '08:58:58'], [], ['11:03:54', '11:04:53'], ['11:45:51', '11:50:26'], [], []]

Answer (score 0):

You could use groupby from itertools to form the groups for you.  You simply need to provide it with a function that will return the same value for times that are within 15 minutes from the last starting point.  This can be computed using the accumulate function (also from itertools):

```
from itertools import accumulate,groupby

times = ["8:00:33","8:05:02","8:06:12","8:58:17","8:58:58","9:53:11",
         "10:03:54","11:45:51","13:54:42"]

groups  = accumulate(times,lambda g,t:g if time_diff(g,t)<900 else t)

grouped = [[*g] for _,g in groupby(times,key=lambda _:next(groups))]

print(grouped)
# [['8:00:33', '8:05:02', '8:06:12'], ['8:58:17', '8:58:58'], 
# ['9:53:11', '10:03:54'], ['11:45:51'], ['13:54:42']]
```

If you don't want to use libraries, a simple loop on times can produce the same result by adding times to the last group or adding a new group based on the difference with the first entry of the last group:

```
grouped = []
for t in times:
    if grouped and time_diff(grouped[-1][0],t)<900:
        grouped[-1].append(t)                        # add to last group
    else:
        grouped.append([t])                          # add a new group
```

[EDIT] Injecting empty groups for each chunk of 1:30 between groups:

Use zip() to get consecutive pairs of groups and compare the end of the first group with the start of the next one.  For each chunk of 1.5 hour (5400 seconds), insert an empty group using a nested comprehension:

```
grouped[1:] = [ g for g1,g2 in zip(grouped,grouped[1:])
                  for g in time_diff(g1[-1],g2[0])//5400*[[]]+[g2] ]

print(grouped)
# [['8:00:33', '8:05:02', '8:06:12'], ['8:58:17', '8:58:58'], 
# ['9:53:11', '10:03:54'], [], ['11:45:51'], [], ['13:54:42']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and very good explanation. Just one more question if you have the time. How do I check if groups are more than 1h :30m apart from each other and give empty brackets for each 1:30m passed. Example: ["17:48:50","17:49:50"],[],["19:43:25"]] or ["17:48:50","17:49:50"],[],[],["21:43:25"]]

Comment: yea you are right I want multiple empty groups if they are 3 hours or more. Could you help me with that.

Comment: Fixed it bro. It was my function it was returning float instead of int. But wow, thank you for quick response you are master of the craft. Just left me without words. Thanks for being good and kind in this not so much world.